# 2D Arrays exercise need to solve

Tags: java, arrays

I want the program to print like this:

Matrix elements: 
2
4 6
8 10 12
14 16
18

But i got stuck. This is my code :

```
    int[][] matrix = new int [5][];
    matrix[0] = new int[1];
    matrix[1] = new int[2];
    matrix[2] = new int[3];
    matrix[3] = new int[2];
    matrix[4] = new int[1];
    System.out.println("\n\n Matrix elements: ");
    for(int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) { 
        for(int j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++) {   
            System.out.print(matrix[i][j] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println("\t");    
    }
```

And the program only print like this:

Matrix elements: 
0
0 0
0 0 0
0 0
0

Thank you for helping!

Comment: You forgot the code that assigns values to these arrays.

Comment: `0` is the default value in an `int[]` cell. Like Eran said, you might need to put some value into this array

Comment: PS : Something tells me we will soon see the question to how to change this code to accept the number of row ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It won't work, because you forgot the second assignment. Your code is just saying: "Hey Java, I need a two dimensional array and it should have 5 rows",  and after that you added "Ah, and row 1 should have one column, row 2 two columns, ..." but you didn't mension the values you want to have there.

Here is what you can do:

```
    int[][] matrix = new int [5][];
    // one by one assignment
    matrix[0] = new int[1];
    matrix[0][0] = 0;

    matrix[1] = new int[2];
    matrix[1][0] = 2;
    matrix[1][1] = 4;
    //...
```

Or:

```
    int[][] matrix = new int [5][];
    // This way you just say what you want to have inside the array and java will
    // evaluate the size needed
    matrix[0] = new int[]{ 0 };
    matrix[1] = new int[]{ 2, 4 };
    //...
```

Or:

```
   // like the previous one, but in a two dimensional way. 
   int[][] matrix = new int[][] {
            { 0 },
            { 4, 6 },
            { 8, 10, 12 },
            { 14, 16 },
            { 18 }
    };
```

The methods will lead to the same result, but I highly recommend to use the third, because it raises readability.

Comment: Please add an explanation as well as code if people look here in future an explanation will be essential

Comment: If OP doesn't understand why he doesn't have the correct output, he probably won't understand this code, so you should explain what those are doing. Nice example of the possibilities by the way

Answer (score 1):

First of all you have to assign value to each array element.As describe in below code.

```
    int temp=0;
    for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++) {
            temp=temp+2;
            matrix[i][j] = temp;
        }

    }
 for(int k = 0; k < matrix.length; k++) { 
        for(int l = 0; l < matrix[k].length; l++) {   
            System.out.print(matrix[k][l] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println("\t");    
    }
```

hope this will helps you.

Comment: Nope.It does not solve OP's problem.It will print 0  
1 2  
2 3 4  
3 4  
4

Comment: @Akshay i am just explaining him to assign some values to array element .
here i had mention exact code in my edited answer.
just check once.

Comment: Ok.The first code that you posted did not solve the question.Always try to post the entire ans to avoid down votes.Cheers

Comment: @Akshay actually, for those homework question, it is better to only put the OP on the correct tracks without giving the full answer ;)

Comment: @AxelH..yeah true

Answer (score -1):

Assign value to element. You print 0 value because int[i][j] is 0.

```
        int [][] matrix = new int[5][];
        matrix[0] = new int[1];
        matrix[1] = new int[2];
        matrix[2] = new int[3];
        matrix[3] = new int[2];
        matrix[4] = new int[1];

        for(int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) { 
            for(int j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++) {   
                matrix[i][j]= j+i+2;
            }    
        }


        System.out.println("\n\n Matrix elements: ");
        for(int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) { 
            for(int j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++) {   
                System.out.print(matrix[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println("\t");    
        }
```

or ...

```
        int [][] matrix = new int[5][];
        matrix[0] = new int[1];
        matrix[1] = new int[2];
        matrix[2] = new int[3];
        matrix[3] = new int[2];
        matrix[4] = new int[1];


        System.out.println("\n\n Matrix elements: ");
        for(int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) { 
            for(int j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++) {   
                System.out.print(i+j+2 + " ");
            }
            System.out.println("\t");    
        }
```

Comment: If you need clarification from OP, post a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Don't answer to @ray like this since his comment was before your edit. And to be fair, yes this solve the problem but this don't answer it. You should explain the code to be complet ;)